# Continuously check a file modified or not using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which is to continuously check the modified date of a file is changed or not. And if it is changed, then display a message box that "File has been modified". i have a simple code and but it showing some error in the execution..

```
@echo off
setlocal
set FileName=F:\test\tester.txt
set FileTime=0 
:loop
for %%X in (%FileName%) do (
     if %FileTime% NEQ %%~tX (
        echo file modified
     ) else (
     echo no change )
set FileTime=%%~tX
)
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>nul
goto :loop
pause
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: We aren't a code writing service; please at least attempt it, and ask a new question if you have any problems (also see [help] and [mcve] before doing so, if you need to).

Comment: sounds as a job for the archive attribte. See `attrib /?`

Comment: Rojith, please email me using the email address listed in my profile, and I'll formulate a new question for you (that shouldn't be downvoted).

Comment: Actually I made the question fastly, Thatswhy you all feel bad, sorry.. Please help me, I got stucked on exectuion failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final Code. Thanks for your supports.

```
 @echo off
  setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value')    do        
set "dt=%%a" 
set "td.YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
set "td.YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "td.MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "td.DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set "filename=%td.MM%%td.DD%%td.YY%.txt
:loop
for %%i in (%filename%) do (
        echo %%~ai|find "a" >nul && (
        cscript MessageBox.vbs "Today's Schedule Changed. Modified Time: %time%. Please Check AVScheduler ON or OFF."
        attrib -a %%i
) || (
rem echo no change
)
)
timeout 1 >nul
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the file time, rather use the Archive attribute (historically used to determined if a file needs to be archived because it was changed; Every time, the OS does a write to the file, it also resets this attribute):

```
@echo off
set filename=tester.txt
:loop
for %%i in (%filename%) do (
  echo %%~ai|find "a" >nul && (
    echo %filename% was changed %time%
    attrib -a %%i
  ) || (
    rem echo no change
  )
)
timeout 1 >nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: Its working.. Thanks