# Copy files from one folder to another, if files in subfolder are modified

Tags: batch-file, replace, directory, copy, synchronization

Dears,

I have a code that works for copying the files, from one to another folder, it also search if the file exists in the subfolders.

But I want it to check if files are modified and replace the old ones.

This is the code that works for me.

I would appreciate for your help.

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("C:\test1\*") do (
    dir "C:\test2\%%~nxI" /A-D /B /S >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 copy "%%I" "C:\test2\" >nul
)
```

Comment: Take advantage of the archive attribute, similar to what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951081/batch-script-that-monitors-for-file-changes/36952026#36952026) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480736/continuously-check-a-file-modified-or-not-using-batch-file/36482428#36482428)

Comment: Pretty sure you could do this in a single line of code if you used `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY`.  Regardless of that, I am surprised that you didn't see the `EXIST` option when you were reading the help file for the `IF` command.

Comment: @Squashman I could appreciate you help. Thanks